# Aggregate PHP XDebug data with KCacheGrind

Tags: php, profiling, aggregate, xdebug, kcachegrind

Is there any way to aggregate profile data previously taken by PHP XDebug?

I have managed PHP XDebug to put the data related to one request to single file. When I open that file in kcachegrind, it displays all the requests aggregated in that file. However, each request has its own stack trace (I understand, it may change). Is there any way to see profile data aggregated from all the requests? I don't care if it's not 100 % accurate or if some calls are missing, I just need the brief overview over all daily operations.

Disclaimer: kcachegrind is not requirement, I just found it the best tool so far.

Comment: ouch.. All daily operations? What's the volume (in megs) of trace files you want to summarize?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Combine all files into one:

```
cat cachegrind.out.* > cachegrind.combined
```

Open the cachegrind.combined and select "Parts" tab on bottom right of the window. You will see multiple parts of profile listed there. Select them all (CTRL+a or use mouse) and you will see summed data of all these profile files.

Answer (score -1):

The report generated is TEXT and can be parsed so it should not be to complicated to build a parser that generates reports.
I use WinCacheGrind for windows and find it very good as besides a detailed tree it also shows a general combined time/function and how many calls it has.

Comment: Any idea how to create such parser?

Comment: Well from scratch :) load the file and loop throu it's lines taking the data putting it in arrays nicely based on what it represents. It has a pharsable format otherwise there would not be any CacheGrind program. Try http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/ if you do not like to get dirsty and code from scratch.